# localStorage array of objects handling

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, local-storage

Array of JSON objects are stored in HTML5 `localStorage`.
For now delimiter is **`;`**
For accessing and modifying array of objects from `localStorage`,  `split(';')` and `join(';')` operations used.

However ,delimiter approach looks unstable.
For instance **`;`** could be met inside objects attribute and `split(';')` operation will be uncorrect.

It could be used **`;;`** for delimiter,but i'm not certain it will be stable also.

Is there any robust way to handle `localStorage` presented as array of objects,as far `localStorage` saved as `String`?

**EDIT**

one of stoppers is that array of object couldn't be saved to localStorage as classical: `"[{},{}]"`
`localStorage` converts it automatially to String like `"{},{}"`

my current data within `localStorage`:

```
"{"name":"volvo","id":"033"};{"name":"saab","id":"034"}"
```

**assumption**
perhaps,i can add `[` at the start and `]` at the end,but it looks not gracefull

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just convert the objects to JSON strings:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify(objects));
```

And vice versa:

```
objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData")));
```

Or you can add multiple objects in the same localStorage value:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify([object1, object2 /*, etc*/]));
object1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData"))[0];
object2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData"))[1];
```

[Here's the DOM storage specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage).

You can also access `savedData` like this:

```
localStorage.savedData = "Hello world"
var foo = localStorage.savedData;
```

This can be used for both getting and setting the data, but it is considered less "safe" than `getItem('name');` and `setItem('name', 'value');`

Comment: hi, i've tested with just String in vacuum,it works OK,however problem is that array of JSON objects saved to `localStorage` as delimited by `,` curly brackets,e.g. `"{obj1},{obj2}"` and i expect `"[{obj1},{obj2}]"`

Comment: Can you edit the actual object / data into your question? I'm not quite sure how the data you're trying to save looks, now.
I'm confused because: `JSON.stringify([{a:1}, {b:2}]);` returns: `"[{"a":1},{"b":2}]"`, like expected.

Comment: I see. That's not a valid JSON string. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: i get it from backend using `TidyJSONWriter`,com.day.cq.commons.TidyJSONWriter

Comment: Hm, I see.
The easiest thing to do would be to make sure `TidyJSONWriter` uses `,` as delimiter instead of `;` (If possible), then save that to your `localStorage` with added `[]`: `localStorage.savedData = '['+data+']'`
It's kinda ugly but at least it can be properly parsed, then.

Answer (score 0):

Read variables:

`var xyz = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'element' ) );`

Store variables:

`localStorage.setItem( 'element' , JSON.stringify(xyz));`

where `element` is the name of the local storage variable and `xyz` the name of the js variable.