# Dividing local Storage into Sections

Tags: javascript

right now i set something like this below

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
```

I just want to save different value for "username" in different page..

So is there something likebelow ?

```
localStorage[page1].setItem("username", "Smith");
```

Comment: For different page with same key you can not store new value but override.

Comment: Store JSON objects instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Yup, storing objects is the way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702100/localstorage-array-of-objects-handling

Comment: i just want to protect "username" keyword for different pages !

Comment: @Diodeus Any other alternative  ? something simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a json object with the data associated to a specific page, e.g.

```
localStorage.setItem("page1", JSON.stringify({username: "Smith"}));
username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("page1"))["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is limited to storing key/value pairs. However, you can create a Json object with values for username on different pages, stringify it and store as a key/value pair.  check out [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)