# how do you print local storage in readable format?

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with localStorage and am still learning how to access values within the object. I have successfully returned a bunch of objects within localStorage, and now I'm wondering how to turn these comma separated key, value pairs into a legible format.  I have tried the `replace` method as well as looping through the object, but have had no luck. I'd really appreciate your help.

This is my localStorage output:

```
{"question":"How do you get close to the president?","your_answer":"buy him some chocolates","answer":"bribe your way in","check":false}{"question":"What is your code name?","your_answer":"John","answer":"Mikhalov","check":false}
```

I would like for it to look like this:

```
Question #1: blahblah 
Your Answer: blah
Check: Wrong


Question#2: ...
```

Attempt#1:

```
    if (counter == questions.length-1){
        output = ''

    for(var i =0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        output += localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).replace(/"{"/g,"\r\n");
    }}
```

Attempt#2

```
    if (counter == questions.length-1){
        for (var key in localStorage){
            for (option in key){
                console.log(option)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See  `for (var key in localStorage){ console.log(key) }` and  `for (var key in localStorage){ console.log(localStorage[key]) }` - this should give a clue.

Comment: why not post this as an answer @user2864740?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this returns `undefined` in the console:    for (var key in localStorage){
    a = localStorage[key]
    console.log(a["question"])   }

Comment: @str4gut You should post your above question as a separate question. However, here's the answer anyway: Your console is a Read Eval Print Loop (REPL), which evaluates what you type in, and returns the last expression. Since the for-loop is a statement (and therefore doesn't return any value), the console returns undefined.

Comment: @st4rgut `a` refers to a string. This is because `localStorage[key]` returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{"question":"How do you get close to the president?","your_answer":"buy him some chocolates","answer":"bribe your way in","check":false},{"question":"What is your code name?","your_answer":"John","answer":"Mikhalov","check":false}];

obj[0].question;
```

convert into array.

Comment: How would the OP "convert into array"? What use is this?

Comment: http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702100/localstorage-array-of-objects-handling

Comment: The OP is using `localStorage` like a normal JavaScript object as-a-map - he/she doesn't indicate a need to store more complex values.