# How to store and update a localStorage key object which has properties of different data types?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

this is my first time using `localStorage` and I would like to store a `localStorage` key which is an object that has properties of different data types ,for example the key "`localstor`" ,it is an object containing two properties :

```
localstor= { userMsg : String , userInfo : (Object) { ID: String , username: String , pwd :String } }
```

the property `userMsg` is of type `String` while the property `userInfo` is of type `object`.

I know how to set and get an item containing only objects based on 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702100/localstorage-array-of-objects-handling) , but in my case I don't know how to set and get this kind of key? and espacially if I want to update the object userInfo in localstor how to do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage#answer-2010948

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: hi, I sow the question ,but that did not helped ,I know how to store an object in localStorage by JSOn parse , but what if I had like the above example ,how can I update the content of user info and then restore it in localstor?

Comment: why the minus ? it is not the same question ! I don't understand!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question, and if I did, please tell me so I can correct my answer, but I think what you are trying to do is manipulate an item you kept in cache with `localStorage`, and this data, for instance, is an object that contains data of multiple types.


So lets say you have your object `localstor` (I added some tabs so it's easier to see and debug);

```
var localstor = {
  userMsg : "Message",
  userInfo :{
              ID: "SomeID",
              username: "SomeUsername",
              pwd : "SomePassword"
            }
}
```

Putting it into localStorage is super easy (as you pointed out you already know how to do) so you only need to choose a key. Here, I chose "obj" as key:

```
localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(localstor));
```

As you might have noticed, I used a function `JSON.stringify()`.
I  did it because since you have an object with objects inside, you need to convert it into a **String** to store it. JavaScript has this function already built-in so you don't need to install anything.

**How do I retrieve and update the localstor object now?**

Very easy.
I retrieve the object with the *localStorage.getItem()* function, passing the "obj" I have setted before, and this result I need to convert it back to the Object type (since we stored it as a String before, remember?) using the `JSON.parse()` function. After that, I can edit the properties of the object as I would do with any other object:

```
localstor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("obj"));
localstor.userInfo.username = "AnotherUsername";
```

I can set the new object back to the LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(localstor));
```

And that's it! now when I retrieve it again, the new value for username will be there.

Full code here:

```
var localstor = {
      userMsg : "Message",
      userInfo :{
                  ID: "SomeID",
                  username: "SomeUsername",
                  pwd : "SomePassword"
                }
    }

    //Put the localstor object into the cache
    localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(localstor));


    //Retrieve the object
    localstor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("obj"));
    //Change the username property
    localstor.userInfo.username = "AnotherUsername"; 
    //And put the editted object back to cache
    localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(localstor));
```

If you have any doubts yet, please tell me so I can answer in a better way!

Comment: Hello, I appreciate you for answering my question , your explanation is perfect and your answer is exactly what I nedded ,thank you very much

Comment: +1 for your answer and your attitude. Your response is technically apt and is also cheerful, observant and accommodating. This approach increases the value of SO. 